# Return CSS selector for a React Component

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, selenium, css-selectors

I need to interact with an online application written by a third-party developer, part of which is written in React. To interact with the site I'm driving Firefox via Selenium and Python. I can use traditional CSS selectors to interact with most of the site, but the parts written in React have random autogenerated class names that change every time the devs rebuild their app. There are no IDs found on any DOM elements except for the root node.

**How can I get a unique CSS Selector for a DOM element, given a specific React Component in the virtual DOM?**

For instance, by using [React Develper Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) I see this tree:

```
Context.Provider
├─ Context.Provider
│  └─ gs
├─ Context.Provider
│  └─ styled.div
│     └─ styled.button
└─Iv
```

**How can I get a unique CSS Selector for the DOM element that represents the `Context.Provider > Context.Provider > styled.div > styled.button` React Component?**

I have seen the [React Element Selector Query](https://github.com/baruchvlz/resq) NodeJS library, but I need something that can run in Python, or can be interpreted from within Python and Selenium.

Here is example code from the app I'm targeting:

```
<div id="root">
  <div class="sc-hTtwUo kyYkJm">
    <div class="sc-jqUVSM bZjAcv">
      <button class="sc-jSMfEi kXusAw">Foo</button>
      <button class="sc-eCYdqJ ddMHci">Bar</button>
    </div>
    <div class="sc-kgUAyh bqLSQt">
      <div class="sc-kgflAQ kGhjap">
        <div class="sc-kDDrLX civFbY">
            ... Lots more ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Other than the button element text, that is actual production HTML. Note that this is **not** deliberate obfuscation, rather this is not uncommon for React apps.

##### Where do the React libraries store a mapping that X component is represented by Y DOM element? It is that mapping which I am trying to locate and read.

Comment: It actually is deliberate in the sense that webpack doesn't mangle css by default...

Answer (score 1):

You can check for id, if ids are given to each tag then can be accessed very easily.

for instance

```
<div class="randon-class" id="renderingID">
    This is some div rendering some content
<div>
```

You can access the div by `#renderingID` this will give you the required properties.

Comment: Thank you, but no IDs are found on any DOM elements except for the root node. I'll add that information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, there is a pattern when a class name is transformed, like underscore. So you can split using that and check for given classname. For example, we are looking for `.content` under `.body`. So element will have className as `body_content_<hash>`. So, we can split using and check if it has `content`

**Note:** This approach is based on string manipulation. So if the classname has same delimiter, it will fail.

```js
document
  .getElementById('btnSearch')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    const searchClass = document.getElementById('txtSearchId').value
    const elements = searchElements(searchClass)
    highlightElement(searchClass, elements)
  })
  
function searchElements(className) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(`[class*="${className}"]`)
}

function highlightElement(className, elements) {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.border')
    .forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove('border')
    })
    
  Array.from(elements).filter((element) => {
    const classes = element.className.split(/[ _]/);
    const matched = classes.includes(className);
    if (matched) {
      element.classList.add('border')
    }
    return matched
  })
}
```

```css
.border {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

div {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="txtSearchId" />
  <button id="btnSearch">Search and Highlight </button>
</div>
<div class='body_1nu21'>
  <div class='body_content_2nasiy'>
    <div class='body_card_21dfl'>test</div>
    <div class='body_card-test_2345a'>test</div>
    <div class='body_card-blue_9hysh8'>test</div>
    <div class='body_card_7hdsg'>test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rajesh. Unfortunately the class names are completely random strings. I've added example code, from the actual production site, to the question. And these class names change every time the React devs recompile their app.

Comment: @dotancohen Issue is, once compiled, there is no react on DOM. Its just plain HTML. React is the background processing. So you do not have React components. So maybe talk to dev team, if you can and ask for the tool that does it. If your markup is actual markup, you'll notice `sc-` is repeated. So maybe you can search parent component and navigate manually.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have access to the team who maintain the app - they're deep in BigCorp and BigCorp does not "support" scripting their site - only Human access. They have no problem with scripted access, but won't change their processes to support it. **However**, given that React Developer Tools can show the Virtual Dom tree, the information about the structure of the App exists. I'm not sure how that extension works under the hood, but there must be some way to translate this Virtual DOM into the CSS Selectors because that extension highlights the DOM element that is hovered over.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to go by structure / innerText in this case.
For example:

```
#root > div > div > button => Foo
#root > div > div > button + button => Bar
```

Comment: The structure would include a lot of `:nth-child()` targeting which is fragile. The React component names do not change from update to update.

Comment: All you have to go on though is what's in the DOM: in your example that's text and #root.

Comment: Do the React libraries not store a mapping somewhere that X component is represented by Y DOM element? It is that mapping which I am trying to locate and read.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to get at those things, but it sounds like the app renders client-side which means that data you need is either in a json string in the html or loaded through a fetch / xhr / websocket, so that's the way to get it.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely client side because the Chrome extension has access to the mappings. If I get the time I'll look at the extension and see what it does, I do believe it is open source.